# How do I make a Bash script run a command in the background in another Terminal window?

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm new to bash script and I need to make a script that runs the following commands:

```
service apache2 start
airmon-ng start wlan0
airbase-ng -e FREEINTERNET -c 1 -P wlan0mon
ifconfig at0 192.168.1.129 netmask 255.255.255.128
route add -net 192.168.1.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 gw 192.168.1.129
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface at0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.4:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcpd.conf -pf /var/run/dhcpd.pid at0
service isc-dhcp-server start
```

My big doubt is how to make the script open the `airbase-ng -e FREEINTERNET -c 1 -P wlan0mon` command in a different terminal and keep executing both airbase and the remaining commands. I’m using Kali 64-bit with GNOME.

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Comment: Actually on second thoughts, it looks like you're trying to set up a malicious wifi hotspot.

Comment: I really don’t think this question deserves the downvotes (or close votes) it’s getting… the formatting is a little wonky, yeah, though a suggested edit going through the queue fixes that, but it’s a fairly clearly worded question about a specific issue. It’s true that the script could be used for nefarious purposes, but it could also be used legitimately, e.g. for penetration testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run something in the background by suffixing it with `&`. If you want to run something in a new GNOME Terminal window, you can do so with `gnome-terminal -e`. Putting those together, to run your `airbase-ng` command in a new GNOME Terminal window while letting the rest of your script continue to run:

```
# …
airmon-ng start wlan0
gnome-terminal -e 'airbase-ng -e FREEINTERNET -c 1 -P wlan0mon' &
ifconfig at0 192.168.1.129 netmask 255.255.255.128
# …
```

Comment: I usually supply internet through this hotspot, the traffic is redirected to a login page. No nefarious or malicious purpose.
Sorry for the noob question though.
If I use the gnome-terminal -e within the script I get an error message saying it doesnt know option -c (the channel option on airbase) when I run it. Which apparently means that gnome-terminal -e does call the command but does not read the command options/syntax. What should I do?
If I don't make it run in a different terminal will the rest of the commands still run in the background?

Comment: Thank you so much. First time using this forum and got an answer really fast. I was a bit afraid it would take ages for someone to say anything. Thank you very very much. Cheers
P.S.: I'll try to be more carefull with the formatting in the future :)

Comment: @Humberto: Make sure that the entire command you want to run in the other window is quoted; otherwise, `gnome-terminal` will think that you’re trying to pass options to *it*, rather than the command you’re trying to run. Let me know if that doesn’t work. As for your other question, yes, you absolutely can omit the whole `gnome-terminal` thing and just use `&`; the script will continue to run in the background, but its output will be interleaved with other commands. (You could redirect to a file or something if that’s a problem.)